# Всё ли правильно

Tags: обучение

```
Где бы вы ни были, Лаймбук всегда будет рядом.
```

Нету ли в данном предложении ошибок?

Comment: Только не "нету", а "нет"

Comment: Людмила, можно и ''нету''. Это устно-письменная речь. Поэтому вполне корректно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере ошибок нет. А  вот в комментарии есть. Нельзя сказать ошибки русского языка или какого-н. другого языка. Правильно: Нету ли в данном предложении ошибок ?

Comment: @Серж, спасибо. А "вы" с большой буквы в каких случаях пишется?

Comment: Можете прочитать здесь.[Как писать ВЫ и ВАШ -  с прописной или со строчной буквы?](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_88)